# simple HttpURLConnection POST file multipart/form-data from android to google blobstore

Tags: android, file, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data, blobstore

I have very little idea how html works.What i want to do is exactly similar to the following **but on android**

```html
<body>
    <form action="<%= some_url %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

I tried the following code -

```
private static void postToUrl(String url_to_upload_on,
        String file_name_with_ext, byte[] byteArray) {

    String attachmentName = "file";
    String attachmentFileName = file_name_with_ext;
    String crlf = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    try{

    URL url = new URL(url_to_upload_on);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty(
        "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(
            connection.getOutputStream()); 
    request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
    request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
        attachmentName + "\";filename=\"" + 
        attachmentFileName + "\"" + crlf);
    request.writeBytes(crlf);
    request.write(byteArray);
    request.writeBytes(crlf);
    request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + 
        twoHyphens + crlf);
    request.flush();
    request.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

this gives me no direct errors but when i get error-stream using-

```
 Log.w(TAG, "connection.getErrorStream() = " +      connection.getErrorStream());
```

i get this-

```
12-14 18:25:54.911: W/uploadToBlobStore(30558): httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream() = com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$FixedLengthInputStream@426dd5a8
```

with no success.

PS- I am uploading a file to google blobstore

PS- I can not use Apache http libraries or its multipart class as android says its depreciated

**EDIT 1**

Now I am using the following code but it is working only for files less then 2.3Mb -

```
private static void postToUrl3(String url_to_upload_on,
        String file_name_with_ext, byte[] byteArray, String mimeType) {

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;

    try {

        httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url_to_upload_on);


        MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);            
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(byteArray, file_name_with_ext);           
        reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);         
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity.build());


        httpClient.execute(postRequest);// takes time

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("uploadToBlobStore", "postToUrl Exception e = " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (httpClient != null) {
            Log.w("uploadToBlobStore", "connection.closing ");
            try {
                httpClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w("uploadToBlobStore", "connection.closing errot e = "
                        + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to make it work with larger files?

**PS-** i am sending it to blobstore and i did set the `maxUploadSizeBytes`and `MaxUploadSizeBytesPerBlob` to 30MB.I am not able to figure out the issue with size because google blobstore documentation says -

> Google App Engine includes the Blobstore service, which allows applications to serve data objects limited only by the amount of data that can be uploaded or downloaded over a single HTTP connection.

So can it be a problem with http connection? and if so, how can i configure it.

Comment: I was able to upload a file using multiPartEntity, check out the code I posted in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222980/urlconnection-always-returns-400-bad-request-when-i-try-to-upload-a-wav-file
Tick green if it works! cheers!

Comment: The answers to this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java

Answer (score 9):

use [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/) and use following snippet (taken from [recipes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes))

adjust the header values according to what your server expects.

```
private static final String IMGUR_CLIENT_ID = "...";
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
// Use the imgur image upload API as documented at https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
    .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
    .addPart(
        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"title\""),
        RequestBody.create(null, "Square Logo"))
    .addPart(
        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\""),
        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("website/static/logo-square.png")))
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .header("Authorization", "Client-ID " + IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
    .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
    .post(requestBody)
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply.Do i have to add this 'okHttp' as an external library?

Comment: ok i added okHttp using jar. but eclipse gives me error "The type okio.ByteString cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" at 'RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("website/static/logo-square.png")))'

Comment: @FlyingMonkey I suggest you use Android Studio.. if you absolutely need to use eclipse however, download the okio jar (https://github.com/square/okio) and add it the same way you added okhttp

Comment: yes, don't use Eclipse, it's been discontinued by Android SDK.
You don't need to add any jars manually in Android Studio, just write a line in your gradle file. Use okhttp with retrofit to make the calls much more simple. 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/
http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: THANKYOU! This code is not the best solution, but the pointer to `okhttp` is! I just want to emphasise to anyone battling this problem of uploading a file from Android that okhttp (currently okhttp3) is the way to go! When I started on this and saw okhttp mentioned I was wary of it, because one is always reluctant to use a free library you've never heard of. However, having been forced to this solution, I can't recommend okhttp too highly. It looks to have a strong maintenance record, is easy to use and install (into AndroidStudio), and solves a problem which other methods didn't (for me).

Comment: For current and neater solutions with okhttp as of Dec 2016, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512547/how-to-use-okhttp-to-upload-a-file/30498514#30498514

Comment: @StephenHosking [internally android has been using okhttp since 4.4 that's why i recommend using it](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/482563299511250944)

Answer (score 5):

As alternative you can use *Retrofit*.

You can specify a call like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/user/photo")
Call<User> updateUser(@Part("photo") RequestBody photo, @Part("description") RequestBody description);
```

then create it like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .build();
GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

and finally execute it like this:

`service.updateUser(Photo, description).enqueue()`  --> **asynchronous**

`service.updateUser(Photo, description).execute()` --> **synchronous**

See the documentation [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score -2):

Volley is a good http library for multipart data.
`AndroidMultiPartEntity` class is for progress listener.

```
    public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity

    {

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
    super();
    this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode, final ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mode);
    this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary,
    final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mode, boundary, charset);
    this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
    super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
    }

    public static interface ProgressListener {
    void transferred(long num);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private final ProgressListener listener;
    private long transferred;

    public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
                                final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(out);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.transferred = 0;
    }

    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        this.transferred += len;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        this.transferred++;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }
    }
    }

    Call the Async task like this
    new UploadFileToServer().execute();


    The Call method:
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return uploadFile();

    }

    private String uploadFile() {

        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.Seeker_Image_Upload);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void transferred(long num) {
                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                }
            });

            File sourceFile = new File(Path);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("logo", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            //entity.addPart("website", new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));

            // String emailaddress = UserActivity.emailaddress;

            /*preferences = SeekerProfile.this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            email_address = preferences.getString("EMAILADDRESS", "");*/
            entity.addPart("EMAILADDRESS", new StringBody(email_address));
            entity.addPart("OPER", new StringBody(Operation_recruiter_logo_upload));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);
        enter code here
        }

    }
```