# Google Cloud Storage XML API Policy document accessed through Google CloudEndpoint API. Lexical Error: Unmatched input

Tags: google-cloud-storage, httpurlconnection, google-cloud-endpoints, android-xmlpullparser

I am getting the following error

> `InvalidPolicyDocument`The content of the
>   form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy
>   document.Policy document parsing error: Lexical
>   Error: Unmatched Input: <s>

My Async Task to call a HTTPURLConnection is below. The multipartv1 class is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276466/simple-httpurlconnection-post-file-multipart-form-data-from-android-to-google-bl).

Inside an AsyncTask doinbackground

```
{multipartv1.addFormField("key", filename_insert_value);
multipartv1.addFormField("bucket", “myapplication”);
multipartv1.addFormField("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
multipartv1.addFormField("GoogleAccessId", “myapplication@appspot.gserviceaccount.com");
multipartv1.addFormField("acl", "bucket-owner-read");
multipartv1.addFormField("success_action_redirect", "https://myapplication.appspot.com/getpolicydocumentsuccess");
multipartv1.addFormField("success_action_status", "201");
multipartv1.addFormField("x-goog-meta-programname", this.current_program_name);
multipartv1.addFormField("x-goog-meta-membername", this.member_element_id);
multipartv1.addFormField("x-goog-meta-tag1", tag1);
multipartv1.addFormField("x-goog-meta-tag2", tag2);
multipartv1.addFormField("x-goog-meta-tag3", tag3);
multipartv1.addFormField("x-goog-meta-tag4", tag4);
multipartv1.addFormField("x-goog-meta-tag5", tag5);
multipartv1.addFormField("policy", this.policy);
multipartv1.addFormField("signature", this.signature);

multipartv1.addFilePart("file", new File(this.file_absolute_path));

List<String> response_multipart = multipartv1.finish();
Log.e(Tag, "SERVER REPLIED:");
for (String line : response_multipart) {
Log.e(Tag, "Upload Files Response:::" + line);
}
```

The "policy" is generated from my backend (Google App Engine) using Google Cloud Endpoint API. This is as policy document supported by Google Cloud Storage XML API as listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument).  The "policy" works perfectly when accessed through a Webapplication.

The "policy" looks like this -

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

My fear is when I add the parameter for "policy" in my HttpURLConnection, something is messed up. The code to add the "policy" parameter is this -

```
 public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                    .append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                    LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.flush();
        }
```

The HTTP Post call is here -

```
public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

The boundary string is this

```
   String boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the error shown?

Comment: solved this by breaking down the string to the following policy_doc = """{multipartv1.addFormField("key", filename_insert_value), multipartv1.addFormField("success_action_redirect";""" + "https://myapplication.appspot.com/getpolicydocumentsuccess"  + """);
multipartv1.addFormField("success_action_status", "201");"""

Comment: Great to hear. You should post that as a self-answer now.

Comment: i'm getting same error how did you solved it. `Policy document parsing error: Lexical Error: Unmatched Input: <'>`