# MultipartUtility Android Extra bytes

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, upload

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong in the code below? I'm sending part of the file from Android/Java to Asp.Net C# Web API.

the array of bytes received on the server side has two extra bytes that are breaking the checksum of the file.

I'm using the MultipartUtility class posted here: [simple HttpURLConnection POST file multipart/form-data from android to google blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276466/simple-httpurlconnection-post-file-multipart-form-data-from-android-to-google-bl)

here is my code to send the array of bytes to the server:

```
 public void addFilePart(String fieldName, byte[] stream) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "file";
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();

    outputStream.write(stream);
    outputStream.flush();

    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}
public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
    List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--");
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    // checks server's status code first
    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpConn.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        httpConn.disconnect();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I can post the whole class if needed, it's really the link above.

Thank you for your help.
Sean

Comment: Which extra bytes are received?

Comment: it looks like 29 and -123 !

Comment: The closing boundary is missing.

Comment: Please dont post code in comments. Use your post.

Comment: can you tell me where the closing boundary is missing?

Comment: After the last line feed. Compare with the link you quoted.

Comment: Can you please repost the code with the line you think I need to add? I've been looking at this code for hours and I can't see what you're suggesting... to me, both the link and my code are 100% the same... I'd really appreciate if you can add the line of code you think should be added. Thank you.

Comment: Your finish() function writes the closing boundary. But before that you have two line feeds. Try to do with one.